# SQL - JOIN add additional requirement in another table

Tags: mysql, join

I'm looking for some guidance on the following.   I have two SQL tables A and B.

Table A Contains a list of languages

| language_id | language |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | English |
| 2 | French |
| 3 | Spanish |

I would like select all languages, and do a check on Table B to see if it exists for a user in table B.  A user can select multiple languages, and many users could opt for any give language.  The Query will be for a specific userid.

Table B

| language_id | userid |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 2 |  |
| 3 | 2 |  |

I am not sure how to add the condition "WHERE userid = 1", I am hoping it will provide the following result.

$stmt = "SELECT A.language_id, A.language, COUNT(B.userid) FROM A INNER JOIN B.language_id = A.language_id ORDER BY A.language";

So for userid 1 it would produce the following.

| language_id | language | COUNT() |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | English | 1 |
| 2 | French | 1 |
| 3 | Spanish | 0 |

I am just trying to check if the user has selected each language or not.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below query for this.

```
select A.language_id, A.language, COALESCE(B.counter, 0)counter
FROM tableA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT language_id, COUNT(1)counter FROM tableB where userid=1 group by language_id
    )B ON A.language_id = B.language_id
```